# Unable to use 'y1' as a float variable in C

Tags: c

**Introduction:** I'm building a simple program to input the coordinates of two numbers from user and print the distance between those coordinates.

**Issue:** The problem is that the compiler isn't letting me set `y1` as a float variable. If I change `y1` to `ycord1` or any other variable name, the program works fine.

I'm having no issues setting `x1` and `z1` as float variables, the problem is only with `y1`.

Here's the screenshot of the error I'm getting:
 [image: screenshot]

**The Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float square(float, float);

float x1, y1, z1;
float x2, y2, z2;

float distance = 0;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    printf("Enter coordinates of Point 1: ");
    scanf("%f, %f, %f", &x1, &y1, &z1);

    printf("Enter coordinates of Point 2: ");
    scanf("%f, %f, %f", &x2, &y2, &z2);

    distance = sqrtf(square (x2, x1) + square (y2, y1) + square (z2, z1));

    printf("Distance between the 2 points is %.3f\n\n", distance);

    return 0;
}

float square(float a, float b)
{
    float c = a - b;
    c = c * c;
    return c;
}
```

---

I've tried 2 different compilers but both are producing the same error.

I tried searching `Is y1 a reserved variable in C` on Google, but couldn't find any meaningful results. Let me know if I also need to provide a screenshot of the code working when I replace `y1` with any other variable.

Comment: It most likely comes from `math.h`.

Comment: `_CRTIMP double __cdecl y1 (double); //line 273`
Found in `math.h`
Source : GNU 6.3.0, IDE: Codeblocks

Comment: `scanf("%f, %f, %f", &x1, &y1, &z1)`??? What are these commas and spaces doing in `scanf` format string? Is this intentional?

Comment: @alk That worked! But I didn't understand how moving the definition inside `main()` fixed that

Comment: @AnT That is not the cause of the error. I've always used `scanf` like that

Comment: @Harshit Jindal: It could be another error.

Comment: @AnT that too, but the compiler clearly believes `y1` is `double` not `float`.

Comment: @Weather Vane: The compiler believes `y1` is `double (*)(double)`, not `double`. Which has already been explained: in the (arguably poor quality) implementation the OP is using, there's a global symbol called `y1` already. It is a `double y1(double)` function.

Comment: If you look at the man page for `y1`, you'll see it's one of several poorly named Bessel functions.  The names I saw are `y0`, `y1`, `yn`, `y0f`, `y1f`, `ynf`, `y0l`, `y1l`, `ynl`.  If you use `math.h`, then you need to avoid those names at the file level.  Another reason to avoid global variables I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`y1`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/y0.3.html) is a [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of the second kind. However, the identifier that you're using is **not an identifier reserved by the C standard library**, but comes from POSIX.

If you request that the compiler sticks to *standard*, without extensions, for example with `gcc` use `-std=c11`, then `<math.h>` doesn't declare that identifier. The linker should *in theory* just fill in those symbols that are yet unresolved. Of course if you link in **any library** that expects `y1` to actually be the Bessel function and not your variable, then you will have wholly undefined behaviour - perhaps you should use `static double y1` here.

---

Then of course, in your case the best thing would be to have `y1` as a *local* variable instead; there the global declaration of `y1` wouldn't matter.

Comment: Even though in strict `-std=` modes the identifier might not be declared in the header file, it is usually remains exported as an external symbol by the library. Strict `-std=` modes do not disable that export and do not resolve the conflict.

Comment: @AnT it absolutely must resolve it here, because we're talking about the math library, otherwise the implementation isn't standard-compliant.

Comment: I hope you are right. For example, `-std=c11` will disable the declaration of `gets`, but it will not prevent you from linking to it directly, since it is still present in the library.

Comment: @AnT Yes, it would be linked against in absence of a definition.

Comment: @AnT added disclaimer for not linking in libraries that expect y1 to have the libm definition.

Comment: 1+ for Bessel, for POSIX, for `-std=xyz`! :-)

Answer (score 2):

y1 returns a bessel function of order 1. It is not reserved, but it is defined in math.h. Even if you don't include math.h, it is defined as a built-in function by the compiler (most probably so people don't use it as global variables.)

You cannot override it as a variable in the same global space. And no one expects a short-named variable as a global variable anyway, since global variables were meant to be used across functions or even multiple source files and modules, so usually are more descriptive.

Since you are only using y1 and all the rest of the global variables inside main() function, define them as local variables of main():

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    float x1, y1, z1;
    float x2, y2, z2;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you google enough (e.g. [here](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/121246-error-%C2%91y1%C2%92-redeclared-different-kind-symbol.html)) you'll find that on Mac there is already an `extern double y1 ( double );` somewhere. Stupid of them to give something such a "vague" name, but there you go.

Your only solution if you want to keep y1 in global scope is to use a different variable name (as you have already found). You can have a "different" `y1` in different scope e.g. inside `main`.

Comment: No need to gxxgle. Grepping all includes involved would have done.

Comment: as @alk suggested, simply moving the definition inside `main()` works perfectly fine without changing the variable name, but I'm still trying to understand why that happens.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler tells you that `y1` is already defined. And as you define `y1` on global scope you can conclude `y1` is already defined on global scope.

C does not allow redefining a symbol differently in the same scope it is already defined in.

What C does allow is defining a symbol inside another scope. Doing so would "shadow away" the "outer", the other definition of the symbol with the same name.

So to fix your issue just move the definition of `y1` inside to `main()`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Make the declaraction local, if you really want to use `y1` as variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float square(float, float);



float distance = 0;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    float x1, y1, z1;
    float x2, y2, z2;

    printf("Enter coordinates of Point 1: ");
    scanf("%f, %f, %f", &x1, &y1, &z1);

    printf("Enter coordinates of Point 2: ");
    scanf("%f, %f, %f", &x2, &y2, &z2);

    distance = sqrtf(square (x2, x1) + square (y2, y1) + square (z2, z1));

    printf("Distance between the 2 points is %.3f\n\n", distance);

    return 0;
}

float square(float a, float b)
{
    float c = a - b;
    c = c * c;
    return c;
}
```

I have just read this thread.: https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/121246-error-%C2%91y1%C2%92-redeclared-different-kind-symbol.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @HarshitJindal If it is helpful then please accept it as answer. This will also help others...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the same program(redef.c) using gcc.

> $ gcc redef.c -lm
>
> redef.c:6:11: error: ‘y1’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
>    float x1, y1, z1;
>
> In file included from /usr/include/features.h:367:0,
>                   from /usr/include/stdio.h:27,
>                   from redef.c:1:
>
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:251:1: note: previous declaration of ‘y1’ was here
>    __MATHCALL (y1,, (*Mdouble*));

Symbol **y1** is already being used in math library, thats why this error.
Gcc compiler directly point out the prev definition location.

Comment: It is not because of `math.h`. I tried removing that, and it still shows the same error. Refer to the other answers to understand what actually caused this issue

Comment: Its not because of math.h but mathcalls.h. Gcc clearly mention it in output.

Comment: Please update your answer with the solution that would fix the issue, to make it useful for the rest of the people as well. Only the cause of the solution won't help anyone

Comment: alk has already answered the question it seems. Do not use the y1 in global space. Put this variable inside main().